# Uniform continuity, boundedness, linearity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let $X \subset C(\mathbb R;\mathbb R)$ be the space of all continuous functions $u: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where

$$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u(x)=0$$

provided with the $\sup$-norm. Let $k \in L^1(\mathbb R)$, $u \in X$ and

$$(Ku)(x) := \int_\mathbb R k(x-y)u(y)\,dy, \,\,\,x \in \mathbb R.$$

How can I show that all functions $u \in X$ are uniformly continuous and bounded and that $K$ is a mapping from $X$ to $X$, linear and bounded?

Appreciating some food for thought.

Comment: what is $L^1(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: @Masacroso that means $\int_{\mathbb R} k < \infty$

Comment: @Tesla No, it usually means $\int_{\Bbb R}\vert k\vert <\infty$

Comment: Oh ok thanks, was mistaking then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u$ be continuous such that $u(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$. Let us show that $u$ is uniformly continuous. Let $\varepsilon>0$. We need to find $\delta>0$ such that
$$|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |u(x)-u(y)|<\varepsilon$$
First off, there exists $M$ such that
$$|x|\geq M\Rightarrow |u(x)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{3}$$
by definition of the limit. We now do a case study.

1. If $|x|\leq M$ and $|y|\leq M$. Since $f$ is continuous it is uniformly continuous on the compact interval $[-M,M]$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that
   $$|x|\leq M\wedge |y|\leq M\wedge |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |u(x)-u(y)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{3}<\varepsilon$$
2. If $|x|\geq M$ and $|y|\geq M$ then
   $$|u(x)-u(y)|\leq|u(x)|+|u(y)|\leq\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{3}<\varepsilon$$
   without further conditions on $x$ and $y$.
3. If $|x|\leq M$ and $|y|\geq M$, assume for instance that $x\leq M\leq y$, the other case being similar. If $|x-y|<\delta$ we also have $|x-M|<\delta$ hence:
   $$|u(x)-u(y)|\leq |u(x)-u(M)|+|u(M)|+|u(y)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{3}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{3}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon$$

A similar (and much simpler) argument shows that $u$ is bounded.

Comment: thank you, easy to understand. Didnt know I had to do a case study. I guess boundedness follows directly from our limit condition.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform continuity and boundedness of $u$ was answered and indeed it is pretty obvious.

Linearity of $K$ comes from the linearity of integral and it is bounded beacause if $||f|| \leq 1$ then :
$$ ||(Kf)(x)|| = ||\int_\mathbb{R} k(x - y)f(y) dy|| \leq  Sup_x \int_\mathbb{R} |k(x - y)f(y)|dy \leq Sup_x \int_\mathbb{R} |k(x - y)|dy = ||k||_{L^1}$$
Now I prove $K: X \rightarrow X$ :

Suppose that $\epsilon$ is a positive real number and consider that $B$ is a big bounded interval in real numbers such that $\int_{B^c} |k| < \epsilon$

Consider $u \in X$ and suppose that $u$ is bounded by $M$, now as $u$ is in $X$ if $|x|$ is big enough then 
$|u(x-y)| < \epsilon $  for all $y$ in $B$, now we have (for those $x$):

$$ |(Ku)(x)| = |\int_\mathbb{R} k(x - y)u(y) dy| = |\int_\mathbb{R} k(y)u(x - y) dy| \leq \int_\mathbb{R} |k(y)u(x - y)| dy = \int_B |k(y)u(x - y)| dy + \int_{B^c} |k(y)u(x - y)| dy <  \epsilon \int_B |k(y)| dy + M \int_{B^c} |k(y)| dy < \epsilon (||k||_{L^1} + M)$$
So $Ku$ is in $X$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. How do we know that we can find a "big bounded interval" though such that $\int_{B^c} |k| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Oh wait that follows from the work for  the first part. Okay cool.

Comment: I don't how did you get it from the first part but it is a standard theorem and it can be easily proved by dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Well there exists $M>0$ such that $u(x) < \epsilon$ for $|x| > M$. Now $B=[-M,M]$ for example and then $\int_{B^c} |k| <\hat \epsilon$